# Can I say 'He rushed back at the table'?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

The grammar assistant I use suggests I should use 'to' instead of 'at' after the verb 'rush'. And I perfectly understand why. But can I use the preposition 'at' to create a sort of ellipsis?

Let's make a couple of examples:

> 'He rushed back **at** the table.'

In this case, the person in question doesn't just rush to the table but also sits **at** it.

Another example:

> Mary rushed **at** her opponent to confront her.

In this case, Mary doesn't just rush to her opponent, but she does so in a more challenging way, as the preposition 'at' in many cases suggests.

So, can I use the preposition 'at' in this way?

Comment: If you *rush **at** [an opponent]*, that means you're ***attacking*** him. People don't usually attack tables, so your first example is completely non-idiomatic. The second example isn't very good either, because you seem to be trying to combine the sense of *rushing **to** [somewhere]* (hurrying to *arrive* there, referring to "direction of movement" or "intended destination") together with the *rush at = attack* sense. But that doesn't really work.

Comment: You could rush at an obstacle such as a gate, maybe? Like a bull? With the intention of jarring it open, perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: A gate, maybe. But a *table?*

Comment: You should have seen my grandma when she'd had a few.

Comment: Tables suitable for rushing at might include constables and notables, In an emergency, even large vegetables.

Answer (score 3):

As you understand, **at** can mean either "where an action takes place", as in *They sat at the table*, or "with X as its goal", when used with some other views, mostly verbs of motion, as in *He flew at the policeman* or *She aimed at the target.*

**rushed** is a verb of motion, so "rushed at the table" means "rushed *towards* the table", or "rushed, with the table as the goal".  (Or maybe somehow "Performed the action of rushing, while at the table.")  There's no way for it to mean "rushed to and then sits".

Reference: [At - English Grammar Today - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/at)

Comment: @Fra The "sit" part can be implied by some constructions, since people normally sit at tables. "Come to the table" includes an implication that you will sit down. So "He hurried back to the table" could *imply* that he also sat, as long as he's a diner, not a waiter.